# Just need some enlightenment about .equals

Tags: java, equals

```
Integer a = new Integer(1);
Integer b = new Integer(1);
Long c = new Long(1);

System.out.println(a.equals(b));
System.out.println(a.equals(c));
```

Question is why does a.equals(c) gives a false?

Comment: Nobody to VTC an exact duplicate.  Amazing!

Comment: @devnull I'm not convinced it's an exact duplicate. Similar definitely, but this is comparing two objects, whereas the linked is comparing an object and a primitive.

Answer (score 5):

From [`Integer.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> The result is `true` if and only if the argument is not `null` and is an `Integer` object that contains the same int value as this object.

`c` is not an `Integer`, so `a.equals(c)` returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Because, you are using Integer class's `equals` method which does follows:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Integer) { 
            return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The condition fails here `if (obj instanceof Integer)` as the obj i.e. `c` in your case is an instance of `Long`.

Answer (score 0):

because both object are not of same `Class` one is `Integer` and other is `Long`, it will not only compare values when you say `.equals()`

Answer (score 0):

The equals of Integer (and most classes) start with checking if the class of the parameter is equal to the objects own class. If not, equals will return false. This makes more sense if you would try to call equals between an integer and a string, they cannot be compared on values the same way as integer and long can. Therefore, all classes that are not integer and are calling equals on an integer object will return false.

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the source of Integer.equales(Object obj) you'll see why:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Long is not an instance of Integer.

Answer (score 0):

In short: because `c` is not an `Integer` object. You're calling `Integer#equals(Object)` and passing a `Long` in as the parameter. The source code for `Integer#equals(Object)` is:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Because `obj` is a `Long` and not an `Integer`, the `if (obj instanceof Integer)` check fails and the method then returns `false`.